# importing 12M products into magento2 instance?

Tags: magento2, cloud

For client, it is required to import 12M products into magento2 instance and I wonder, if it can handle such big dataset ?

The hosting platform is siteground's cloud, I insisted that customer should use dedicated server for this purpose but he wants to stay on this cloud platform.

Indexing is quite slow on one million, so I wonder is importing of this database is possible at all ?

Do anyone have experience with that huge lists of products?

Magento2 is CE of course, for importing i use custom edited magmi for magento2 which is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 CE do not support so many products from the box.

If you do not update many products (<10k) every day and you have only one store view, indexation should not be a problem for you. But MySql based Search will not work for you.

> Do anyone have experience with that huge lists of products?

Only on cutomized version  and with custom search module.

Comment: Is there an "official" limit of products for M2 CE?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism No, because it highly depends on your servers and customization. Maximum tested profile for CE https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/extra_large.xml have 1M product. More details see in https://magento.com/resources/white-paper-magento-2-site-performance-and-scalability-optimizations

Comment: You need to create your custom import script, use ElasticSearch for search. You may need to use MongoDB. You need many optimizations to support 12M products on a native Magento CE. You can try to have a look to the EE version which contain some optimizations for huge catalog.